# Most reliable way to draft an outlook calendar invite with a teams meeting using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, microsoft-teams

I have created a vba module to draft calendar invites based on data inserted to an excel sheet. A new calendar invite is created for each row of inserted data. As of right now, once the calendar invite is drafted, the user would have to manually add a Teams meeting.  I am looking to have a teams meeting automatically included in the calendar invite, and if possible, ensure that anybody invited can join the meeting without having to be let in.

My code follows very similar logic to this snippet i found when searching for a solution, but I have not included it as it also has confidential info:

```
Sub setmeeting()

Dim O As Outlook.Application
Dim OAPT As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set O = New Outlook.Application

Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
OAPT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

With OAPT

    .RequiredAttendees = "abc@gmail.com"
    .OptionalAttendees = "abc@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "I Love VBA"
    .Start = "11/21/2019 12:00:00 PM"
    .End = "11/21/2019 12:30:00 PM"
    .Body = "Hello World"
    .Location = "Cubicle"
    .Display
    .Send

End With

Set OAPT = Nothing
Set O = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have am aware of and have tried the SendKeys method:

```
SendKeys "{F10}", True
'Switch to ribbon shortcuts
SendKeys "H", True
'Hit the Microsoft teams meetings button, requires teams to be installed
SendKeys "TM", True
'Now to add signature: Switch to meeting location button
```

But i know that the SendKeys method is not the most reliable, and this program needs to work consistently every time its run across many different devices. I also need to ensure that there is absolutely no chance that it affects other applications if the active window is somehow changed. Is there a more reliable way to add a teams meeting to an outlook calendar invite using VBA?